# LDAP Authentication with JSF and Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jsf, tomcat, ldap

I am trying to develop a web project but it is required to authenticate the users with LDAP, I am doing something like this:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://host:port");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"user@hostname.lab.local");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");

    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

And I do not get any errors, however I need to check status of user in order to give access. What else should I do? Am I going in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP authentication proceeds in two steps.

1. You bind to LDAP as an administrative user that has enough permissions to find the user based on his email address or whatever else you're using as the username.
2. Using the DN of that user as the principal, and the password he supplied as the credential, you attempt to bind as that user.

If all that succeeds, the user is authenticated.